# Illegal Start of Expression Error in Array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, compiler-errors

I am trying to write a method that prompts the user for the size of an array, and then for the value of each index value, to be tested in another driver.

I keep getting an "] expected" error, and "illegal start of expression" error at the `double arr[i]` section and was wondering why?

```
public void setArray(double[] arr)
{
    int size = sc.nextInt();

    double[] array = new double[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter value : ");
        double arr[i] = sc.nextDouble();         //error here
    }       
}
```

This is what the compiler returns:

```
GolightlyScottArray.java:26: error: variable arr is already defined in method setArray(double[])
double[] arr = new double[size];
         ^
GolightlyScottArray.java:26: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
double[] arr = new double[size];
                          ^
2 errors
```

Comment: You should add language tag to your question, add more information on compiler/platform and add the full output of the compiler. It will people to answer your question.

Comment: What is the purpose of `arr` vs `array`?

Comment: Within your loop change **double arr = sc.nextDouble()** for just **arr = sc.nextDouble()**. But what I don't understand is why you're declaring **array** while only populating **arr**

Answer (score 0):

You've already defined the variable "arr" in the method declaration so you can't use define it again, which is what you are doing by putting the word **double** at the start of the line. Remove the word **double** and it will update the existing variable instead of attempting to create a new one.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't solve all of the problems. You would have to assume that for some reason `arr.length` is `size`, when it was passed to the function. Otherwise you'd get an `OutOfBoundsException` when executing. Also, it isn't clear why the OP creates `array` and then never uses it.

Comment: You are correct, there are a few things to be looked at here. I am assuming OP is looking for help with his compilation error and will be updating the code afterwards to do what he/she needs. If they need more help later they can ask another question.

Comment: Thank you for the input, very new to Java and a little out of my depths. Appreciate the help.